# Can't stop while loop with a char

Tags: java, while-loop

Below is a program that is intended to convert user input to a letter score. The code works as intended however, my "endGame" method runs at start up before I want it too.
    import java.util.Scanner; //I need this to get the user input

```
public class Grade {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    startGame(); // This creates my start game method
    endGame(); // this will end the game
    gradeLoop(); // This creates the letter grade determination
}

public static void startGame() {// Starts the startGame method
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Auto Score OneThousand");
    System.out.println("Please enter your score from 0  to 100 (or press 'E' to exit): ");
}

public static void gradeLoop() {

    String userInput; // assigns user input
    char letter = 'A'; // assign a char that will be updated with the user's
                        // letter grade
    double score = 0.0;
    boolean go = true;

    while (go) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a new Scanner
                                                    // to hold the input
        userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (userInput.equals("E") || userInput.equals("e")) {
            go = false;
            endGame();
            break;
        } else {
            score = Double.parseDouble(userInput);// convert string to
                                                    // double
        }
        if (score >= 90 & score <= 100)

            letter = 'A';

        else if (score >= 80 & score <= 89)

            letter = 'B';

        else if (score >= 70 & score <= 79)

            letter = 'C';

        else if (score >= 60 & score <= 69)

            letter = 'D';

        else if (score >= 0 & score <= 59)

            letter = 'F';

        {

            System.out.println("You earned a letter grade of: " + letter + "\n\n");

            startGame();
        }
    }
}

public static void endGame() {
    System.out.println("Thank you, This ends your Auto Score OneThousand experiance");
}
```

}

Comment: Start by indenting and adding suitable line spaces. This is a wall of text and nigh unreadable.

Comment: Is the given code correct in Java grammar? So looks odd.

Comment: Assume that the individual entering the grades can determine and enter the letter grade without the assistance of the program.  Then, you can use a switch statement instead of if...elseif...else statement, using cases 'a'  through 'e', and 'default' to properly handle single character input.  A continuation variable can control a containing while loop, set to false in case 'E'.

Comment: Thank you chrylis, Ray C, and Adrian M, this was my first post to stack overflow. I a, sorry about the format I had no idea how to post it as I see it in eclipse. I was able to fix the loop however, now my endgame method runs before it is called........

Comment: [If you change the original question to ask a different question, you should ask the different question in another post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer). and it it better to simplify your code logic.

Comment: Thank you CelThi, I am new to this site but I am a quick study, I'll do better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Put the test in the beginning of the loop. Such as

```
boolean go = true;
while (go) {
    System.out.print("Please enter your score from 0  to 100(enter E to exit):");
    String str = grades.next();
    if (str.equals("E")) {
        System.out.println("The program exits!");
        break;
    }
    y = Integer.parseInt(str);
    //following start to process the int y.
}
```

Tip:  There are extra braces in your code, it it better to remove them.